# object permission in django

Tags: python, django, permissions

In my project, users can create items and they can choose whether the item is public to all users.
I'm currently using django-guardian and this method:

```
class Meta:
     permissions = (
         ('can_view', 'CanView'),
     )
```

and `@permission_required_or_403` to control permission.

But in this way, if the user choose public, I have to assign 'can_view' permission to the group of all users.
Would that be inefficient? Is there any way to simplify this process?

---

Edit: when the user choose private, he can specify some other users to view

Comment: Are they going to be specifying specific users to view a specific item, or, is it always all users can view vs. no users can view.

Comment: when the user choose private, he can specify some other users to view